# Jersey 2.27 & Guice - Has anyone been able to successfully run them together?

Tags: dependency-injection, jersey, jax-rs, guice, jersey-2.0

I am trying to run them together but keep on running into one issue after other.

Version details:

- Guice : 4.2.0
- Jersey : 2.27
- Java : 10

I am running this with org.glassfish.hk2 : guice-bridge

Following is the bridge code I am using

```
GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(serviceLocator);
GuiceIntoHK2Bridge guiceBridge = serviceLocator.getService(GuiceIntoHK2Bridge.class);

guiceBridge.bridgeGuiceInjector(SiteScoutServletContextListener.getInjector());
```

Comment: _"keep on running into one issue after other"_ - What are the issues?. I got it working [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52564924/2587435) with Java 8. I think if you use Java 10, you will run into problem with an incompatible asm version. You need to update that. See my comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52530707/jersey2-hk2-dependency-injection-automatically-gives-abstractmethoderror-org#comment92067912_52530707)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52660446/2587435